# How to add or remove layers using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to use javascript and dojo to add and remove layers.

Comment: I want how to add layers dynamically in arcGis API VERSION 4.0.please send me an example as soon as possible...please request

Comment: Please do not leave questions as answers. Also, asking people to do things ASAP does generally not help, as everyone here is helping out in their spare time. Please read the [tour].

Answer (score 9):

Use [esri.Map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html)'s [addLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#addlayer) and [removeLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#removelayer) methods. Both take the layer to add or remove from the map as an argument. You might also be interested in [map.removeAllLayers()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#removealllayers) and [map.reorderLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#reorderlayer).

Finally, one thing that sometimes trips people up is getting a reference to layers in the map. The recommended approach is to [assign an ID to your layers when you create them](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/layer-amd.html#id). If you don't manually assign an ID, the map assigns one for you. You can get these id's by looking at [map.layerIds](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#layerids) and [map.graphicsLayerIds](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#graphicslayerids). Both are arrays of strings. Once you have an ID, get the associated layer using map.getLayer("some_layer_id").

Comment: it might also be constructive to say that layers in the js api are map services (a group of arc map data layers) not the individual data layers within the map service. Currently you can't modify what layers are in that map service but I think that is changing at 10.1

Comment: Derek,
Upon your suggestion, I tried the following ways to remove a layer (mapservice) from the map: 1. map.removeAllLayers(); 2. for (var j = 0; j < map.layerIds.length; j++) { var layer = map.getLayer(map.layerIds[j]); map.removeLayer(layer); } I had NO success removing the mapservices from the Map. After executing the code above, I could still see the mapservices. Any ideas?

Comment: @LearningGIS24 can you post this as a separate question? Comments on an answer aren't really the place for new discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In Version 4.x, use the following map methods:

```
map.add(layer);
map.remove(layer);
map.removeAll();
```

For more info, check out the [4.x JS API Methods for Map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#methods-summary).